# android pdfviewer / fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidpdfviewer

417/5000
Hello

I have a pdfview that works perfectly, for against it I can not add it to a fragment I use:

- `implementation 'com.github.barteksc: android-pdf-viewer: 2.8.2'`
- `implementation 'com.github.barteksc: android-pdf-viewer: 3.1.0-beta 1'`

Here is the code of my pdfview and my fragment

```
public class magasineFragment extends Fragment  {

    public static magasineFragment newInstance() {
        magasineFragment fragment = new magasineFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pdf_fragment, container, false);


        return view;
    }
}
```

next pdf.class

```
class pdf : AppCompatActivity() {

    internal lateinit var pdfView:PDFView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.pdf)

        pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView) as PDFView
        RetrivePdfStream().execute("http://www.marseillemairie11-12.fr/fileadmin/Images/documents/kiosque/lemag-jan2019.pdf")


    }

    internal inner class RetrivePdfStream : AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream>() 
    {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg strings: String): InputStream? {

            var inputStream: InputStream? = null
            try {
                val url = URL(strings[0])
                val urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                if (urlConnection.responseCode == 200) {
                    inputStream = BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.inputStream)

                }

            } catch (e: IOException) {
                return null
            }

            return inputStream
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(inputStream: InputStream) {
            pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem with that code? Why can't you add it to fragment?

Comment: Hello, the code works perfectly in activity but does not display anything when I integrate it to the fragment I must make a mistake but I do not know where

Comment: show your fragment code that does not work

Answer (score 0):

- I hope this help you
- this code in Kotlin read PDF file from Assets folder
- and display it in fragment

  ```
     class PdfRendererBasicFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {


         private val FILENAME = "table.pdf"
         private val STATE_CURRENT_PAGE_INDEX = "current_page_index"
         private val TAG = "PdfRendererBasicFragment"
         private val INITIAL_PAGE_INDEX = 0   
         private lateinit var fileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor
         private lateinit var pdfRenderer: PdfRenderer    
         private lateinit var currentPage: PdfRenderer.Page    
         private lateinit var imageView: ImageView   
         private lateinit var btnPrevious: Button
         private lateinit var btnNext: Button
         private var pageIndex: Int = INITIAL_PAGE_INDEX
         override fun onCreateView(
             inflater: LayoutInflater,
                  container: ViewGroup?,
                        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
           ): View {
         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pdf_renderer_basic, container, false)
           }

            override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image)
            btnPrevious = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.previous).also {   it.setOnClickListener(this) }
            btnNext = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.next).also {  it.setOnClickListener(this)}

          if (savedInstanceState != null) {
           pageIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_CURRENT_PAGE_INDEX,   INITIAL_PAGE_INDEX)
           } else {
          pageIndex = INITIAL_PAGE_INDEX
           }
              }

          @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
           override fun onStart() {
              super.onStart()
                   try {
                       openRenderer(activity)
                              showPage(pageIndex)
                      } catch (e: IOException) {
                          Log.d(TAG, e.toString())
                    }
                      }

                  @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
                 override fun onStop() {
                    try {
                      closeRenderer()
                   } catch (e: IOException) {
                      Log.d(TAG, e.toString())
                        }
                    super.onStop()
                          }

                override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
                    outState.putInt(STATE_CURRENT_PAGE_INDEX, currentPage.index)
                    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
                       }


                    @Throws(IOException::class)
                   private fun openRenderer(context: Context?) {
                    if (context == null) return

                   val file = File(context.cacheDir, FILENAME)
                  if (!file.exists()) {
                  val asset = context.assets.open(FILENAME)
                  val output = FileOutputStream(file)
                  val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                  var size = asset.read(buffer)
                  while (size != -1) {
                  output.write(buffer, 0, size)
                 size = asset.read(buffer)
                 }
                 asset.close()
                    output.close()
                   }
              fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file,        ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)

                   pdfRenderer = PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor)
                    currentPage = pdfRenderer.openPage(pageIndex)
                     }

                     @Throws(IOException::class)
                     private fun closeRenderer() {
                     currentPage.close()
                     pdfRenderer.close()
                      fileDescriptor.close()
                     }

                   private fun showPage(index: Int) {
                  if (pdfRenderer.pageCount <= index) return


               currentPage.close()

              currentPage = pdfRenderer.openPage(index)

              val bitmap = createBitmap(currentPage.width, currentPage.height,           Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)


              currentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)
             imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            updateUi()
                }
                private fun updateUi() {
                val index = currentPage.index
                val pageCount = pdfRenderer.pageCount
               btnPrevious.isEnabled = (0 != index)
              btnNext.isEnabled = (index + 1 < pageCount)

              }


               fun getPageCount() = pdfRenderer.pageCount

               override fun onClick(view: View) {
              when (view.id) {
              R.id.previous -> {

             showPage(currentPage.index - 1)
             }
              R.id.next -> {
                         showPage(currentPage.index + 1)
                }
             }
            }

            }
  ```

Comment: PdfRenderer class as a viewer is very bad, most documents are not shown correctly, instead barteksc pdf viewer is much better and much faster.